# How to stub Google Compute InstancesClient for testing?

Tags: go, testing, google-compute-engine

### Problem

I want to test a client I wrote that wraps the the [`InstancesClient`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go@v0.97.0/compute/apiv1#InstancesClient) from Googles Go SDK, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it. Google provides documentation on [how to test code that depends on the SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/testing.md), but this doesn't seem applicable for the compute package:

1. ["Testing gRPC services using fakes"](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/testing.md#testing-grpc-services-using-fakes) fails, since in difference to the `translate` package, the [compute.pb.go](https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto/blob/main/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1/compute.pb.go) doesn't contain any gRPC client.
2. ["Testing using mocks"](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/testing.md#testing-using-mocks) fails, because `Insert` returns an `Operation` which has only private fields and not something like a `InsertInstanceResponse` (see code below).
3. There is also no emulator for the compute engine.

### What I've tried

My client has a field which keeps the underlying `InstancesClient`. I thought of using the following interface as type of the field to abstract the `InstancesClient`. For testing, I could then initialize the my client with a double that fits the interface.

```golang
type instanceAPI interface {
    Close() error
    Insert(ctx context.Context, req *computepb.InsertInstanceRequest,
        opts ...gax.CallOption) (*compute.Operation, error)
}
```

But I cannot find a way to write a double for this interface, since the [compute.Operation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go@v0.97.0/compute/apiv1#Operation) contains only a single field which is private.

```golang
import ( // imports shortened
    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
)

type stubInstanceAPI struct {}

func (s *stubInstanceAPI) Close() error { return nil }

func (s *stubInstanceAPI) Insert(ctx context.Context, req *computepb.InsertInstanceRequest,
    opts ...gax.CallOption) (*compute.Operation, error) {

    resp := compute.Operation{
        proto: computepb.Operation{}, // error: unknown field proto in struct literal
    }
    return resp, nil
}
```

Comment: "but this doesn't seem applicable for the compute package" I don't see why.

Comment: @DanielFarrell could you elaborate your comment a bit? I've listed a reason for each proposed way to test why this way isn't working for the compute package.